# How to disable Spring Batch metadata (or at least force in-memory metadata)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm working on creating a micro service to run some pretty simple batch jobs on our database. I'm running into a problem of Spring Batch looking for its own tables before it runs a job, they don't exist, and I don't want them to.

I've tried many work arounds that I've found here on stackoverflow, all with no luck.

I tried using separate datasources, one to point to the actual database with the business data, and another that pointed to an in-memory h2 database. In this case, I would get exceptions that there was 'no transaction in progress' or multiple data source beans defined even with qualifiers and primary annotations. I tried this with multiple combinations of implementing JobRepository and the entire BatchConfigurer myself with no luck.

I tried to use a separate schema for the batch tables, however some of the same issues occurred and it turns out that wouldn't be an acceptable solution for production either.

So now I'm sort of stuck... I would like to use Spring Batch if possible but the spring batch jobs cannot exist in the business database.

Maybe there is an alternative to Spring Batch that doesn't require a place to store metadata for jobs? Like I mentioned, the batch jobs are fairly simple and if one fails mid-run it could be restarted from the beginning and have no impact on the integrity of the data (maybe one user would get a duplicate email but I can live with that).

If not, I'll probably just end up writing something from scratch.

I'm pretty surprised there's no built-in way to disable metadata tables, although maybe I don't fully understand what Spring Batch is for? The example guide on spring.io seemed to be a pretty simple use case and *barley* made a mention of needing its own tables (it just says that it runs its own `schema-@platform@.sql` file when it starts up).

Comment: So if anyone else comes across this, I ended up scrapping Spring Batch and instead went for using Spring Cloud Tasks (mainly due to other enterprise dependencies) and used an interface to create jobs so they could be easily injected as a collection into the 'runner' that would parse the command line args and spawn the appropriate job. Spring Cloud also tried making its own tables, but was much easier to work around.

Answer (score 1):

Seems, I already faced this issue a few years ago. By default, `spring-batch` load your job execution process in a database. To disable it, you have to `override` the `setDataSource` method in your configuration and set it to empty.

Your configuration should look like this :

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Forgot to add that I tried this too, but when I try to actually run a job I get the 'no transaction in progress' error

Comment: Try this link. Hope it will help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373401/spring-jpa-no-transaction-is-in-progress